# How to get relative xpaths in webdriver for multiple web elements?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<a id="ctl00_cphBody_gvMessageList_ctl02_hlnkMessageSubject" href="Message.aspx?id=3428&member=">DDM IT QUIZ 2017 – Bhubaneswar Edition</a>

<a id="ctl00_cphBody_gvMessageList_ctl03_hlnkMessageSubject" href="Message.aspx?id=3427&member=">[Paybooks] Tax/investment declaration proof FY 2016-17</a>

<a id="ctl00_cphBody_gvMessageList_ctl04_hlnkMessageSubject" href="Message.aspx?id=3426&member=">Reimbursement clarification</a>
```

out:

```
DDM IT QUIZ 2017 – Bhubaneswar Edition

[Paybooks] Tax/investment declaration proof FY 2016-17

Reimbursement clarification
```

How can i get the relative xpaths for these three elements, so that I can get the above mentioned texts.

Comment: Provide the website url please.

Comment: https://www.snapdeal.com/

Comment: please hover over any category and click on any item,

Comment: now, how will i get the relative xpath of for eg: inside electronics> DTH services

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath = '//a/text()'
```

This will return a list of text

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer would be:

- to get all `a` elements of the same type, in this case having an `id` with `ctl00`

  //a[contains(@id, 'ctl00')]
- you can add more restriction, for example add a `href` restriction, to contain a certain string in his value

  //a[contains(@id, 'ctl00')][contains(@href, 'Message')]
- to get all `a` element is enough to just use

  //a

In order to get text, you can use a method to get the text from your framework or add `/text()` to your xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the span class [relative xpath] like the following example along with the mouse operations and keyboard operations. 
Check this out and let me know!

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;  

 public class SnapD {  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
 WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();  
 d.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");
 d.manage().window().maximize();
 d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 System.out.println("Hello Google...");  
 System.out.println("Hello Snapdeal...");
 WebElement wb= d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Electronics']"));
 Actions act=new Actions(d);
 act.moveToElement(wb);
 act.perform();
 System.out.println("Mouse hovered");
 WebElement wb1=d.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='DTH Services']"));
 act.contextClick(wb1).perform();
 act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ENTER).perform();
 act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB)).perform();  

 }  
 }
```

Comment: ThankYou very much for your effort.

Comment: Was I able to help you out?

Comment: Yes, thanks again. I went through the relative path concept.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve smileys from a page? & print on the console. All this using webdriver.